# Why don't my lower level logs write to the file, but the error and above do?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I created a small function to setup logging, with a filehandler for 'everything', and smtphandler for error and above.  Error logs write to the log file and send correctly to email, but debug, info, notset don't, even though setlevel is set to 0 for filehandler.  Why's that?  Code below

```
#logsetup.py
import logging
import logging.handlers

def _setup_logger(name, log_file):
    """Function to setup logger"""

    logger = logging.getLogger(name)

    #Create Formatters
    file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    mail_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s - %(message)s')

    #Create handler, set formatting, set log level
    file_handler_obj = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
    file_handler_obj.setFormatter(file_formatter)
    file_handler_obj.setLevel(0)

    #Create handler, set formatting, set log level
    smtp_handler_obj = logging.handlers.SMTPHandler(mailhost=('smtp.gmail.com', 587),
                        fromaddr='mymail@example.com',
                        toaddrs='mymail@example.com',
                        subject='Error in Script',
                        credentials=('mymail@example.com', 'pwexample'),   #username, password
                        secure=())
    smtp_handler_obj.setFormatter(mail_formatter)
    smtp_handler_obj.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

    # add the handlers to logger
    logger.addHandler(smtp_handler_obj)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler_obj)

    return logger

#mytest.py
import time
import logsetup

if __name__ == '__main__':

    TEST_SETTINGS = config_funcs._get_config('TEST_SETTINGS')

    logtime = time.strftime('%Y%m%d') # -%H%M%S")
    log = logsetup._setup_logger('TEST', TEST_SETTINGS['logging_dir'] + 'Py_Log_%s.log' % logtime)

    log.error('Writes to log file and sends email')
    log.debug('Supposed to write to log file, does nothing.')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, logging needs it's own logging level aside from the handlers.  Setting logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG) right before returning logger causes it to work correctly.  Documentation says

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all
>   messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or
>   delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note
>   that the root logger is created with level WARNING.

Which means that if the handlers are lower level than the root logger (which ERROR is not, but DEBUG is) then the handlers which I guess is a child because I'm getting a named logger?  Not quite sure on the why of it, but that does 'fix' it, in case anyone comes to this later.